# Linux mounts ext4 external drive read only

Tags: linux, mount, arch-linux, ext4, read-only

My laptop has two operating systems, Windows 11 and Arch Linux.

I have a external 4TB HDD formatted to ext4.

When I go into Windows, I normally disconnect the external drive, but not always because I sometimes forget it's connected. I normal use Linux OS.

The problem here is that for some reason, after I boot into Linux, the external drive mount read only!, and up till now, I've been unable to recover from this. This has happened to me twice with different external drives. I don't know if the windows OS changes something in the drive. I can copy the info from the disk but that's all!

I've been looking for a solution for a long time, and it's been frustrating.

I've tried `chmod` and `chown` but the result is that the drive is read only, and nothing happens!

Any Idea how to get around this?

[image: dmesg]

[image: /etc/fstab]

I ran the suggested SMART test and everything looks ok!

```
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always - 0


SMART Error Log Version: 1
 No Errors Logged
```

Did a **umount** and **mount** and everything seams to be back to normal!!!

Comment: Do you see some logs when you run `dmesg`. Also, the file contents of `/etc/fstab` from Linux machine would be useful...

Comment: Hi, @harshavmb  I'm not sure how to add an image, so I edited the inicial post. Hope you can see the images!

Comment: @nonick66 Do not post links to images. Copy and past the text into the question using the code blocks.

Comment: From the images you posted, there was some problem with previous mounts, e2fsck (filesystem check) was performed & mounted as read-only as I see `errors=remount-ro`. Was there any power outage? Or your hardware may be genuinely failing.

Comment: What I sometimes do is reboot from Linux into Windows and vice verse. Could that result in the error?

Comment: Windows will hardly touch the partition that has partition type that it does not recognize. I even run Windows 10/11 VM on daily basis that uses the same drive that the Linux host is running on. (They don't share the same EFI system partition though and the one for the Linux host is masked with a Linux partition type GUID.) Even survives Windows updates perfectly. (IIRC you can't even delete a partition on Windows in Disk Management if the partition type code / GUID is not recognized.)

Comment: To mark a question as answered, select one of the answers – or answer your own question, then select that answer (after 48 hours).

Comment: I don't know why you still post an image after being told that just copy and paste the console text into the question. See [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714) Also read [ask] and take the 1-minute [tour] to know how this site works. You don't edit your question to mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when external drive was not properly disconnected or you shutted down the OS not properly. Then it is working as read-only till time that you check it's file system. Then the drive may be mounted as read-write. It is a function in the OS to make data safe when there might be some file system errors.

To solve this, always safely remove the drive in the operating system.

If this will happen again you will need to check the file system on the drive and then remount it once again in read-write mode.

The commands here are: `mount` and `umount`.

The problem may be related to: file system journal, file system itself, not clean unmount, some strange user behavior in the OS or failing drive.

EDIT: OP has repaired super-block and this solved his problem.

Comment: The drive is about 3 months old! I actually have two drives with the same problem!  Should I run the e2fsck and will this destroy my data?

Comment: @nonick66 even new drives can fail. Check SMART attributes for this drive. Fsck in case of errors of the file system may mess around with some files.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much to all, I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: I found out that it's a problem with the e2fsck. I tried dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda but it can't be found      { /dev/sda contém dados "DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)" }

Comment: @nonick66 Neither of them is supposed to be run on `/dev/sda` but `/dev/sda1` (according to your `dmesg` screenshot, the drive is partitioned and has one partition, which is not the same as "partitionless" btw).

Comment: @TomYan yep, your right, sorry about that. I did find this: 
{
FS Error count:           89794
First error time:         Wed Aug 18 15:49:58 2021
First error function:     ext4_lookup
First error line #:       1708
First error inode #:      87687171
First error err:          EFSCORRUPTED
Last error time:          Tue Mar 22 10:26:52 2022
Last error function:      ext4_validate_block_bitmap
Last error line #:        390
Last error err:           EFSCORRUPTED
}

Comment: I restart the super-block and everything seems OK. I think the problem is solved. The disk is up and running normally now.  I found this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456772/ext2fs-open2-bad-magic-number-in-super-block) to help me solve it too. Thank you all for your help, and sorry for all the noob comments.